# Checking if values exists in Firebase have a weird issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm checking if two values are in the database, if they are I'm bringing the values and storing them into internal memory. Now, when I first launch the app is working good because I don't have the data in the database so I enter in my else statement where I do another thing if the data is not there.

However, when I delete app data from my settings, or reinstall it, it won't check in my Firebase if the data is there, instead it will enter in the else statement, I don't know why.

```
    private void ChequearSiExistenDatos(){

            //chequear if exists la data de las referencias de los archivos de usuario , si existen continuar con la app y bajar esos sino traer el del locale
            mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("URL_UserFiles").child("URL_car_"+sharedPrefs.getString(getString(R.string.str_idioma),"en")).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshotCar) {

                    mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("URL_UserFiles").child("URL_model_"+sharedPrefs.getString(getString(R.string.str_idioma),"en")).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshotModel) {
                        if (dataSnapshotCar.getValue()!=null && dataSnapshotModel.getValue()!=null) {

//DOWNLOAD FROM FIREBASE
}
else
{
//DO SOMETHING LOCALLY
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is because of `sharedPrefs`. SharedPreferences do not persist along app uninstalls, are always deleted. So trying to use a variable from `SharedPreferences` after you uninstall the app is not a good option.

So solve this, a better option will be to store the desired data into the database. It will be there even if you uninstall the app.

Comment: OUCH i was not seeing that i was using sharedprefs in my database reference too, i was using it at the else statment , never saw it

Comment: also is weird because i handle an error if the sharedprefs is not found, and that error is replacing the data reference with "en" at the end... so is not the same ?

Comment: As I see in your code, you aren't doing that. You are just trying to get the data directly from `sharedPrefs` and use it in your `DatabaseReference`. To use this line of code: `dataSnapshotCar.getValue()` fist you need to make sure your reference is working.